# How to position Web Parts in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: css, sharepoint, absolute

Is there anyway to assign 'absolute' positioning to sharepoint Web Parts?

Specifically, I am talking about positioning the 'Search Box' Web Part. I have done a fair amount of research but have not received a definitive article on this.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning will depend on your Layout and the place where you need to insert the webpart - usually it does allow if there is no other positioning given for the webpart, but why do you need to position it absolute and what is the scenario?

Regards
Arjun